# Why does onClickListener not work outside of onCreate method?

Tags: android

When I try to use the `onClickListener` method for a button, variable outside of any `onCreate or onPause or onAnything` method, it does not work. I also cannot even set the value of a button variable outside of an "onAnything" method. Help would be great.

Thanks!

```
public class StartingPoint extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

int counter;
Button add= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
Button sub= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
TextView display= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.i("phase", "on create");
    counter=0;       

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            display.setText(""+counter);
            display.setTextSize(counter);
            Log.i("phase", "add");
        }
    });
    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter--;
            display.setText(""+counter);
            display.setTextSize(counter);
            display.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            Log.i("phase", "sub");
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    Log.i("phase", "on start");
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0); 
    int getfromfile = prefs.getInt("counter_store", 1);
    counter=getfromfile;
    display.setText(""+getfromfile);
    display.setTextSize(getfromfile);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    Log.i("phase", "on stop");
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
     editor.putInt("counter_store", counter);
     editor.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    counter=0;
    Log.i("phase", "on destroy");

  }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? Are you getting an error? Post code showing exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: show your code what you are trying.

Comment: Sorry, code posted...when I try to move the add.conclicklistener method out of oncreate and just into the public class, `Syntax error on token "setOnClickListener", = expected after this token`

Comment: Button add= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd); add this lines after  setContentView(R.layout.main);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing I notice about your code is that you are initializing your views when you declare them, which is before you set the content view. Find view by id will not work until after you do so. Change it so you declare them like

```
Button add;
Button sub;

...
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
```

Also, the error message you are seeing is because you cannot execute that statement outside of a method. You should be doing it inside `onCreate` anyway.

Comment: Why does it not work outside of a method? Sorry, I want to learn about it instead of taking it at face value. Thanks!

Comment: For the same reason that you cannot call any method outside of a method in Java (apart from initializing variables). Besides, you want to set the `onClickListener` in `onCreate`, after you call `setContentView` which allows you to use `findViewById` to get the buttons.

Answer (score 3):

You should go thorugh this blog - [Different Ways To Handle Clicks](http://remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a69/Different-Ways-To-Handle-Clicks.html)