# Syntax error on token "start". Very simple code

Tags: java, android

I am trying to learn some java/android development, but I'm really struggling with the basics.

My code looks like this.

```java
package com.example.app_james3;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer media=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button);
    media.start();  // THIS LINE IS GIVING ERROR: Syntax error on token "start",    Identifier expected after this token

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Can anyone offer advice to get this very simple line working? I've copied others code, so I am fairly sure the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, all statements (anything that doesn't declare a variable or class) have to go in methods or in a constructor. `media.start();` is a statement. Therefore, you should put it in a method.

Because `media.start();` should be executed close to startup time, put it in `onCreate`:

```
MediaPlayer media;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Your initialization code goes here:
    media = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button);
    media.start();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, I know it's frowned upon round these ways if this isn't already known... I can't accept your answer for a few minutes, but I'll accept shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare variable inside the activity but when u initialize value from xml inside the function or after **setcontentview**.
You have to also read below link :-
[Why does onClickListener not work outside of onCreate method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321197/why-does-onclicklistener-not-work-outside-of-oncreate-method)

[When does Application's onCreate() method get called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686482/when-does-applications-oncreate-method-is-called-on-android)

[What's onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810418/whats-oncreatebundle-savedinstancestate)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

MediaPlayer media=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button);
media.start();  // THIS LINE IS GIVING ERROR: Syntax error on token "start",    Identifier expected after this token
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```